# grep a pattern in linux (repetition/occurrence more than n)

Tags: linux, design-patterns, grep, repeat

i have a question here. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

I have an input file as below (col 1 is ID name, col 2 comprises of a set of values).
Is it possible for me to display only the lines where the "NN" occurrences happen equal or more than 3? I guess it might can be done using grep command (pattern options perhaps), but i don know how is it to be done.

Input file:

```
ID_a NN;AT;AA;AC;NN
ID_b NN;NN;NN;NN;NN
ID_c NN;NN;AC;AC;NN
ID_e NN;AG;NN;NN;AC
ID_f AA;TT;CG;AA;TA
```

Desired Output file

```
ID_b NN;NN;NN;NN;NN
ID_c NN;NN;AC;AC;NN
ID_e NN;AG;NN;NN;AC
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep 'NN.*NN.*NN' < input.file`

A list of the features are [here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html)

`.*` refers to any number of characters repeated any number of times. It matches the stuff between NNs.

Comment: @amine If this solves your problem then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
grep -E '(NN.*){3,}' input.txt
```

You can replace `3` with whatever minimum number of repetitions you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'gsub(/NN/,"&")>=3' file
ID_b NN;NN;NN;NN;NN
ID_c NN;NN;AC;AC;NN
ID_e NN;AG;NN;NN;AC
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -F'NN' 'NF>=4' file
ID_b NN;NN;NN;NN;NN
ID_c NN;NN;AC;AC;NN
ID_e NN;AG;NN;NN;AC
```